# Volley synchronous request

Tags: android, android-volley

I just started to use Volley's library to make http calls, and I tried to use the RequestFuture class for synchronous requests, but I fail my attempt to make a simple request. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://myapi-oh.fr/v2/podcasts/x/shows/" + points.get(0).getShowId() + "/streams";

    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, future, future);
    requestQueue.add(request);


    try {
        JSONObject response = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);; // this will block (forever)
        points.get(0).setStreamUrl(response.getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(0).getString("url"));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "error : " + e);
        // exception handling
        Log.d(TAG, "error : " + e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // exception handling
        Log.d(TAG, "error : " + e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "error : " + e);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am encountering the exact same issue, could you explain your solution to the problem (in case you still remember)?

Answer (score -2):

To make a simple request just use the StringRequest class. Below is a small snippet:

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "your_url", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
               //handle response here.
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                //handle error here.
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //return params(if any) to server here.
                return super.getParams();
            }
        };
queue.add(req);
```

Comment: Yes, I already did that on other cases, but this time I want to make it synchronous!